# Unable to Login Anonymously using Firebase onCreate (User is null)

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/AnonymousAuthActivity.java) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) as my guide to create an Anonymous Login for user onCreate but I cannot go through with the authentication process.

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to login a user who opens the activity onCreate anonymously with some uID method and when the user has selected some preferences, prompt him to login.

However, I cannot get past the anonymous login because it fails, below is the activity and Logcat.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    Button initialiser_btn;




    @Override
    public void overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) {
        super.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initialise Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //End initialise Auth

        // Firebase Auth Begins
        /*mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();*/ //Commented out because of confusion
        signInAnonymously();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    Log.d("User Test", "onAuthChanged:signed_in:"+ user.getUid());
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("User Test", "onAuthChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };



       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            /*signOut();*/
        }
    }

    private void signInAnonymously() {

        // [START signin_anonymously]
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("User Test", "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("User Test", "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
        // [END signin_anonymously]
    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }

    public void startInitialise(View v){
        Intent callInitialiser = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InitialiserActivity.class);
        startActivity(callInitialiser);
        finish();
    }
```

Logcat:

```
12-27 23:10:34.058 2081-15281/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
12-27 23:10:34.058 2081-2081/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
12-27 23:10:34.062 2081-15281/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@75880fd
12-27 23:10:34.062 2081-18879/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
12-27 23:10:34.062 2081-18879/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
12-27 23:10:34.063 2081-18879/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                               com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                                Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
12-27 23:10:34.063 2081-18879/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
12-27 23:10:34.063 2081-2375/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
12-27 23:10:34.070 2081-18878/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
12-27 23:10:34.070 2081-2081/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
12-27 23:10:34.070 2081-2081/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
12-27 23:10:34.149 18876-18876/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-27 23:10:34.151 18876-18876/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-27 23:10:34.151 18876-18876/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-27 23:10:34.179 18876-18876/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:34.182 18876-18876/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-27 23:10:34.191 18876-18876/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-27 23:10:34.191 18876-18876/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-27 23:10:34.191 18876-18876/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-27 23:10:34.196 18876-18876/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-27 23:10:34.202 18876-18876/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
12-27 23:10:34.202 18876-18876/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
12-27 23:10:34.500 18898-18898/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-27 23:10:34.501 18898-18898/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-27 23:10:34.502 18898-18898/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-27 23:10:34.530 18898-18898/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:34.533 18898-18898/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-27 23:10:34.545 18898-18898/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-27 23:10:34.545 18898-18898/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-27 23:10:34.546 18898-18898/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-27 23:10:34.552 18898-18898/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-27 23:10:34.558 18898-18898/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
12-27 23:10:34.558 18898-18898/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
12-27 23:10:36.349 18911-18911/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-27 23:10:36.390 18911-18911/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-27 23:10:36.390 18911-18911/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-27 23:10:36.431 18911-18911/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:36.432 18915-18915/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-27 23:10:36.433 18915-18915/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-27 23:10:36.433 18915-18915/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-27 23:10:36.433 18911-18911/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-27 23:10:36.448 18911-18911/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-27 23:10:36.448 18911-18911/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-27 23:10:36.449 18911-18911/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-27 23:10:36.454 18911-18911/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
12-27 23:10:36.455 18911-18911/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-27 23:10:36.461 18911-18923/? W/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder:18911_2
12-27 23:10:36.461 18911-18923/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder:18911_2' failed
12-27 23:10:36.468 18915-18915/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:36.470 18915-18915/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-27 23:10:36.482 18915-18915/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-27 23:10:36.482 18915-18915/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-27 23:10:36.483 18915-18915/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-27 23:10:36.489 18915-18915/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-27 23:10:36.496 1528-10517/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.arixeapps.zeal/.Splash} from uid 2000 on display 0
12-27 23:10:36.501 18915-18915/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-27 23:10:36.506 18932-18932/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-27 23:10:36.507 18932-18932/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:36.512 1528-1540/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 18932:com.arixeapps.zeal/u0a72 for activity com.arixeapps.zeal/.Splash
12-27 23:10:36.528 18932-18939/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-27 23:10:36.528 18932-18939/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
12-27 23:10:36.528 18932-18939/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
12-27 23:10:36.538 1247-1387/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer

                                                 [ 12-27 23:10:36.544  1528: 1551 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x84c7e480, tid 1551
12-27 23:10:36.605 2081-2081/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/SearchService: Abort, client detached.
12-27 23:10:36.614 18932-18932/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.arixeapps.zeal-1/lib/x86
12-27 23:10:36.681 18932-18949/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-27 23:10:36.691 18932-18932/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
12-27 23:10:36.709 18932-18932/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
12-27 23:10:36.709 18932-18932/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-27 23:10:36.709 18932-18932/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
12-27 23:10:36.709 18932-18932/? D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 129195938
12-27 23:10:36.718 18932-18932/? V/FA: Collection enabled
12-27 23:10:36.718 18932-18932/? V/FA: App package, google app id: com.arixeapps.zeal, 1:497208096913:android:2f36bb46a9e137bf
12-27 23:10:36.718 18932-18932/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.arixeapps.zeal
12-27 23:10:36.743 18932-18932/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
12-27 23:10:36.743 18932-18932/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
12-27 23:10:36.747 18932-18949/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9879470
12-27 23:10:36.753 18932-18932/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-27 23:10:36.754 1528-2451/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.arixeapps.zeal/.MainActivity} from uid 10072 on display 0
12-27 23:10:36.764 18932-18953/? V/FA: Using measurement service
12-27 23:10:36.764 18932-18953/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-27 23:10:36.765 18932-18953/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9879470
12-27 23:10:36.772 18932-18932/? W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
12-27 23:10:36.973 18932-18932/? W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(android.content.Context, android.os.Handler, int) took 193.880ms
12-27 23:10:37.069 18932-18932/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-27 23:10:37.075 18932-18932/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-27 23:10:37.118 18946-18946/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-27 23:10:37.122 18946-18946/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-27 23:10:37.123 18946-18946/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-27 23:10:37.154 18946-18946/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-27 23:10:37.158 18946-18946/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-27 23:10:37.167 18946-18946/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-27 23:10:37.167 18946-18946/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-27 23:10:37.168 18946-18946/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-27 23:10:37.176 18946-18946/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-27 23:10:37.180 18946-18946/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-27 23:10:37.187 18946-18961/? W/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder:18946_1
12-27 23:10:37.187 18946-18961/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder:18946_1' failed
12-27 23:10:37.220 18932-18949/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-27 23:10:37.221 18932-18949/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9879470
12-27 23:10:37.234 18932-18953/? V/FA: Using measurement service
12-27 23:10:37.234 18932-18953/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-27 23:10:37.235 18932-18953/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9879470
12-27 23:10:37.236 18932-18953/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7450064
12-27 23:10:37.250 1247-1388/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

                                                 [ 12-27 23:10:37.253 18932:18932 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x99598400, tid 18932


                                                 [ 12-27 23:10:37.253 18932:18932 W/         ]
                                                 Process pipe failed
12-27 23:10:37.307 18932-18932/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.arixeapps.zeal
12-27 23:10:37.310 18932-18932/? D/User Test: onAuthChanged:signed_out
12-27 23:10:37.310 18932-18932/? W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}

                                       [ 12-27 23:10:37.375 18932:18966 D/         ]
                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x995987c0, tid 18966
12-27 23:10:37.375 1247-1388/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
12-27 23:10:37.376 18932-18966/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-27 23:10:37.376 18932-18966/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-27 23:10:37.382 1247-1388/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
12-27 23:10:37.402 1247-1388/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
12-27 23:10:37.444 18932-18966/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 18966: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
12-27 23:10:37.444 18932-18966/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e083fe0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
12-27 23:10:37.524 1528-1551/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.arixeapps.zeal/.MainActivity: +760ms (total +1s23ms)
12-27 23:10:37.530 18932-18932/com.arixeapps.zeal W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
12-27 23:10:37.630 1247-1247/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
12-27 23:10:37.720 1528-1551/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
```

As you can see by this line `12-27 23:10:37.310 18932-18932/? D/User Test: onAuthChanged:signed_out` it is not signing the user in and I am not sure of the reason.

Also, if someone can explain why am I getting this huge of a Logcat without anything being wrong in the Syntax/Code, that'd be appreciated.